# How to update an excel file with openpyxl and preserve the checkboxes?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have a Excel template I need to update to create new files. I use openpyxl to open, edit and save the file under a new name.
When I open the new file I can see that all the checkboxes in the file are gone...

I have tried the following:

`wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(inputf,keep_vba=True)`

But, it doesn't work.. I did have a look
Do you have any suggestion?

Thanks.